# ScrollSpy directive that talks to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scrollspy

I'm new to AngularJS and already on the brink of despair :) My app looks like this ([Not-working example on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OaDalITzFGRCyRJ8oDif?p=preview)):

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='controllers.content' >
  <h2 id="fixed">{{ header }}</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in db" scroll-stop="item">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### JS

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]);
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.controllers'
]);

var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('controllers.content', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.db = [
      { name: "20 February 2014", header: "Today" },
      // ...
    ];
    $scope.header = "Today";
}]);
```

Now basically I want a scroll spy that changes the contents of the `h2` (assume it's fixed to the top) to the `header` property of the item in `db` whenever that item is currently at the top of the viewport:

```
app.directive('scrollStop', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          scrollStop:'='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var $page = angular.element(window)
            var $el   = element[0]
            var last_top = $el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 60;
            $page.bind('scroll', function () {
                var current_top = $el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 60;
                if (last_top >= 0 && current_top < 0) {
                    // HERE!
                    console.log(scope.scrollStop.header);
                    scope.header = scope.scrollStop.header;
                }
                last_top = current_top;
            })

        }
    }
});
```

However, I can't figure out how to talk to the `content` controller from within the directive to **edit** `$scope.header` from within the directive. I understand that the `scope` is a different to the controller's `$scope`, and have a vague feeling that I should use `require` somewhere, but can't figure out how to get it right. Partly also because there seem to be 5 different shorthands for doing anything in AngularJS and they don't always go well together. Any help appreciated, including stylistic guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using isolated scope for you directive. So you canot access to the scope controller. You could comunicate with the controller using a service or using events.

If you want to be able to access to the controller scope directly from your directive, you have to use shared scope.

I hope that it helps. You can find more information about scopes in directives [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

-----------EDIT----------------

I am not sure what you want to do, but in the next code you can see as using share scope, you can acces the data from de parent and making the view refresh with the new data.

```
angular.module('app').directive('scrollStop', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var $page = angular.element(window)
            var $el   = element[0]
            var last_top = $el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 60;
            $page.bind('scroll', function () {
                var current_top = $el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 60;
                if (last_top >= 0 && current_top < 0) {
                    // HERE!
                    scope.$parent.header=scope[attrs.scrollStop].header;
                    scope.$parent.$apply();
                }
                last_top = current_top;
            })

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, I can set `scope: false` to share the parent's scope - but I still can't manipulate it. Changing anything in there just changes the property in the child scope. A code example would be super helpful!

Comment: I hope that his little example help you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The point is not accessing the parent scope, it's __changing__ it so that it updates the HTML. Setting `scope.header = "Foo"` doesn't actually change the scope in the controller, neither does `scope.$parent.header = "Foo"`.

Comment: @Manuel I have done some changes, and know it works. I am not totally sure if it has a good performance, maybe there are othe better ways of doing that.

Comment: Ha, the `$apply` was the key! Thank you so much!!